# Are there any tools for analyzing my solution for good design practices?

Tags: .net-4.0

Are there any tools included with Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate) that perform a review of a solution to determine if it follows, for example, SOLID principles? If not in VS, add-ins are okay. Free is best but will consider purchasing something.

In a nutshell, I'm looking for a tool to analyze a solution, it's projects, and their relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/07/26/fxcop-10-0-is-available.aspx) and [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).

FxCop will analyze you projects only after they are compiled, so not a direct answer to your question.

StyleCop will analyze your C# code files directly for good code and documentation style.

Comment: Furthermore - use StyleCop for Resharper. This will enforce the rules DYNAMICALLY as you code, which really makes all the difference.